# What is the difference between variable_scope and name_scope?

Tags: python, scope, tensorflow

What is the difference between `variable_scope` and `name_scope`? The [variable scope tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope#names_of_ops_in_tfvariable_scope) talks about `variable_scope` implicitly opening `name_scope`. I also noticed that creating a variable in a `name_scope` automatically expands its name with the scope name as well. So, what is the difference?

Answer (score 54):

I had problems understanding the difference between [variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) and [name_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) (they looked almost the same) before I tried to visualize everything by creating a simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def scoping(fn, scope1, scope2, vals):
    with fn(scope1):
        a = tf.Variable(vals[0], name='a')
        b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=vals[1])
        c = tf.constant(vals[2], name='c')
        with fn(scope2):
            d = tf.add(a * b, c, name='res')

        print '\n  '.join([scope1, a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name]), '\n'
    return d

d1 = scoping(tf.variable_scope, 'scope_vars', 'res', [1, 2, 3])
d2 = scoping(tf.name_scope,     'scope_name', 'res', [1, 2, 3])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run([d1, d2])
    writer.close()
```

Here I create a function that creates some variables and constants and groups them in scopes (depending by the type I provided). In this function I also print the names of all the variables. After that I executes the graph to get values of the resulting values and save event-files to investigate them in tensorboard. If you run this, you will get the following:

```
scope_vars
  scope_vars/a:0
  scope_vars/b:0
  scope_vars/c:0
  scope_vars/res/res:0 

scope_name
  scope_name/a:0
  b:0
  scope_name/c:0
  scope_name/res/res:0
```

You see the similar pattern if you open TB (as you see `b` is outside of `scope_name` rectangular):
[image]

---

**This gives you the answer**:

Now you see that `tf.variable_scope()` adds a prefix to the names of all variables (no matter how you create them), ops, constants. On the other hand `tf.name_scope()` ignores variables created with `tf.get_variable()` because it assumes that you know which variable and in which scope you wanted to use.

A good documentation on [Sharing variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope) tells you that

> `tf.variable_scope()`: Manages namespaces for names passed to `tf.get_variable()`.

The same documentation provides a more details how does Variable Scope work and when it is useful.

Comment: I would suggest simplifying this very useful example by dropping the `vals` argument

Comment: I would also suggest changing the name of 'd' from 'res'.  I assume that that is unrelated to the 'res' you passed in as scope2.

Answer (score 39):

When you create a variable with `tf.get_variable` instead of `tf.Variable`, Tensorflow will start checking the names of the vars created with the same method to see if they collide. If they do, an exception will be raised. If you created a var with `tf.get_variable` and you try to change the prefix of your variable names by using the `tf.name_scope` context manager, this won't prevent the Tensorflow of raising an exception. Only `tf.variable_scope` context manager will effectively change the name of your var in this case. Or if you want to reuse the variable you should call scope.reuse_variables() before creating the var the second time.

In summary, `tf.name_scope` just add a prefix to all tensor created in that scope (except the vars created with `tf.get_variable`), and `tf.variable_scope` add a prefix to the variables created with `tf.get_variable`.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about why two scoping mechanisms are needed?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you should create an issue on github asking to better document the difference between the two mechanisms.

Comment: I can speculate. I think the reason to exist two ways to create a variable (tf.Variable and tf.get_variable) is because normally you don't want to share an variable. If you want to share then, you need to create a var with tf.get_variable and use the tf.variable_scope to change scope just to make explicit that you are handling shareable vars. If it were possible to use tf.name_scope in this case, maybe this would decrease the code readability.

Comment: Does that make variable_scope an anonymous scope, while name_scope is a named scope?  If so, wouldn't it make sense to rename 'name_scope' to 'named_variable_scope'?

Answer (score 2):

`tf.variable_scope` is an evolution of `tf.name_scope` to handle `Variable` reuse. As you noticed, it does more than `tf.name_scope`, so there is no real reason to use `tf.name_scope`: not surprisingly, [a TF developper advises to just use `tf.variable_scope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6007#issuecomment-264535954).

My understanding for having `tf.name_scope` still lying around is that there are subtle incompatibilities in the behavior of those two, which invalidates `tf.variable_scope` as a drop-in replacement for `tf.name_scope`.