# TF namescope vs. variable_scope and how they impact variable sharing

Tags: tensorflow, scope

I would like to understand how/why `name_scope` and `variable_scope` are both used in the code below. I have looked at the Tensorflow documentation for these methods and I have also looked at this very helpful SO post: [Difference between variable_scope and name_scope in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215746/difference-between-variable-scope-and-name-scope-in-tensorflow) but that has not cleared up my confusion.

I am trying to reuse some code from [this paper](https://www.kansascityfed.org/en/publications/research/rwp/articles/2017/macroeconomic-indicator-forecasting-deep-neural-networks), and in particular I'm looking at how they coded up an autoencoder. `input_param` is a tensor passed in to a function, and the code is inside the function.

```
with tf.name_scope("input") as sc:
    frednet=input_param

mk_lstm = lambda x: [rnn.LSTMCell(12, use_peepholes=True,
                    initializer=layers.xavier_initializer()) for i in range(x)]
with tf.variable_scope("lstm1") as sc:

    #lstm=rnn.LSTMCell(5,use_peepholes=True,initializer=layers.xavier_initializer())
    lstm=rnn.MultiRNNCell(mk_lstm(2))
    frednet,st=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm,frednet,dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope("lstm2") as scb:  
    #lstm=rnn.LSTMCell(12,use_peepholes=True,initializer=layers.xavier_initializer())
    lstm=rnn.MultiRNNCell(mk_lstm(2))
    frednet,st=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm,frednet,dtype=tf.float32,initial_state=st)

net=sm.flatten(frednet[:,:,:])
#     net=sm.dropout(net,keep_prob=.9)
net=sm.fully_connected(net,num_outputs=1,weights_initializer=layers.xavier_initializer(),
                           weights_regularizer=sm.l2_regularizer(1e-7))
```

**This code works fine BUT I would like to understand why modifications I made caused errors:**

(1) if I delete the `name_scope` portion of the code then my model doesn't really train and keeps printing out zeros.

(2) If I also delete the `variable_scope` portion of the code, then my code won't even run as tensorflow throws some name conflict error.

**Here are my questions:**

(1) What is going on with error (1) described above? How this name_scope help with the "sharing" of the `frednet` variable?

(2) Is there a reason they used first `sc` and then `scb` for the variable scope (first one matches the name scope but second doesn't). My understanding of Python is that these names are scoped only within the `with` clause so why don't all 3 just use the same?

(3) For error (2), is it correct that this is happening because `MultiRNNCell` has default names that it uses, and these are in conflict if I call that function multiple times? Is it always necessary to use `variable_scope` in the event of multiple uses of `MultiRNNCell`?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what type the input_param is...

Comment: @lerner `input_param` is a tensor passed in to a function, and the code is inside the function. I have modified my question to make this celar.